# What is VERSION NUMBER referencing in this postgres CLI command?

Tags: postgresql

What is version number supposed to represent in this CLI command: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres[VERSION NUMBER HERE] start` ?

Comment: The *version number* of whichever version of Postgres you're using?

Comment: @johnsharpe Tried that, didn't work

Comment: can you paste `ls /usr/local/var/` output?

Comment: ls = PG_VERSION  pg_multixact  pg_tblspc
base   pg_notify  pg_twophase
global   pg_replslot  pg_wal
pg_commit_ts  pg_serial  pg_xact
pg_dynshmem  pg_snapshots  postgresql.auto.conf
pg_hba.conf  pg_stat   postgresql.conf
pg_ident.conf  pg_stat_tmp  postmaster.opts
pg_logical  pg_subtrans  postmaster.pid

Comment: hmm, if that's your `/usr/local/var` output, then `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var start ` should work

Comment: Where do I find that information @JNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VERSION NUMBER HERE` usually refers to the major version number (not patch/minor release).

So if you have version 10.3 installed, it should refer to `10`

Note that in 9.6 and earlier, major versions had two digits, followed by a patch version (example: 9.5.4 -- major version is 9.5, minor version is 4).

However, what's more important than the version is what folder exists at `/usr/local/var` -- You could have a data directory that has no versions (i.e., you can do `initdb /tmp/foo` and all your data will go into `foo`, and `pg_ctl -D /tmp/foo start` should get your database started).  A good rule of thumb (though there are situations where this fails) is to look for the directory containing `postgresql.conf`, and that directory is what you would pass as an argument to `pg_ctl -D <dir> start`

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee

Answer (score 0):

By including the version number of the Postgres version in the name of the data directory allows you to have multiple clusters (=instances) running at the same time using the same binaries.

Including the version number in the name of the data directory is not mandatory though, and whether it was done during installation or not depends on which Linux distribution you are using. Every distribution does this slightly differently.

But typically you don't start Postgres through `pg_ctl` but through the systems "service manager", e.g. `systemctl` or `service` depending on the Linux distribution. You can check the service definition where the exact location of the data directory is.